# Navigation bar drop down issue with laravel 5.2 routing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am new to the web development area, been doing C# development for few years now.My problem is when ever i try to view some records using laravel FM(it works fine) but i am left out with non working navigation bar dropdowns.This problem only occurs when i try to use multiple routing segments(which is a must for me) like;

```
Route::get('/viewproducts/view/{id}','ProductController@ViewProduct') ;
```

But the navbar is working perfectly with single route sigment like so :

```
Route::get('addproduct','ProductController@AddProduct') ;
```

I am following this tutorial to create navbar :
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

When ever a view fails to make a working navbar drop down i alter the route so it is only one segment and that view starts to behave well.
The bottom line is i am confused since this shouldn't be an issue at all.Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: The biggest reason for dropdowns to not work is that the bootstrap javascript isn't getting loaded on the page. Check that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment it gave me a strong clue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when ever you branch more in your route laravel starts to look for the resources (js file) in the directory that has the URL name so a fix to this is to include the bootstrap js files as follows in the main blade view .

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
```

instead of :

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```